# Will an old iOS 7 App still be available in AppStore after App was updated to iOS 8 only?

Tags: iphone, ios7, ios8, app-store

We currently have an iOS 7 App in the AppStore that works on iOS 7 and iOS 8 devices. Now we implemented some iOS 8 only features and will publish this App as an update for the current iOS 7 App. I know that iOS 7 devices will not update to the new version but:

Will iOS 7 users still find and be able to install the older iOS 7 App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but this comes with a **tradeoff**:

There are only 3 possibilities to install the old iOS 7 app on an iOS 7 device:

1. You already own the app and can install the old app on your iOS 7 device.
2. If you don’t own the app you have to download it once on an iOS 8 device. After this, the app will be available on your iOS 7 device (assumed you use the same account).
3. If you don’t own the app you can use iTunes to download/buy the app. After this, the app will be available on the iOS 7 device (assumed you use the same account).

Unfortunately the most common usecase to just download the app in the iOS AppStore for the first time will not work.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, iOS 7 user will be prompted that they can't update to this latest version but can download a pervious version of your app.

But there is still the question way not detect whether or not the user can use the new iOS 8 only feature and make it optional in the app. This way iOS 7 user can still enjoy a big part of the app, just not the part for iOS 8.